# How to erase indexes from Elasticsearch with a bash script?

Tags: bash, elasticsearch

I'm trying to build a script that views all my indexes from Elasticsearch, then take the name of the index and cut the date from it and drop it to a file in the /root directory. After that, the script will compare the dates from the file to a date older than 60 days and erase the old indexes.

I am able to drop the dates from the name of the indexes to a file in the /root directory, but when I try to compare it with the date of 60 days ago it does not work.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#storing all the dates that currently in logstash in a file

show_logs=$(curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'| grep filebeat |cut -d"-" -f2 $)
echo result has been stored in a file
# storing the date we want to check aginst in a variable

Date6DaysAgo=$(date +%Y.%m.%d --date='6 day ago' >/root/DateAgo.logstash)
echo date 60 days ago is stored in a file
while read p
do
if [ $(date +%s -r /root/DateAgo.logstash) -ge $(date +%s -r /root/CurrentDates)
echo this date is newer than 6 days ago
fi
done < /root/CurrentDates.logstash
```

My expected result is that the script will be able to erase indexes older than 60 days (the date appears in the name of the file), but currently I'm stuck because for some reason the output of the code shows that all the files are ok to use (for testing purposes I used 6 days).

Current result:

```
this date is newer than 6 days ago
this date is newer than 6 days ago
this date is newer than 6 days ago
this date is newer than 6 days ago
this date is newer than 6 days ago
this date is newer than 6 days ago
this date is newer than 6 days ago
this date is newer than 6 days ago
```

Answer (score 0):

If you not mind, I suggest you to use Elastic ILM(Index Lifecycle Management).
You can do in in kibana management or using API.

1. Create your policy

   ```
   curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_ilm/policy/your_policy" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "policy": { "phases": { "delete": { "min_age": "60d", "actions": { "delete": {} } } } }}'
   ```
2. Put your policy to index

   ```
   curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/filebeat*/_settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "index.lifecycle.name": "your_policy"}'
   ```
3. Run start or stop policy

   ```
   curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_ilm/start"
   ```

   Or

   ```
   curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_ilm/stop"
   ```

It'll set policy to filebeat* and it'll be deleted 60 days after it is rolled over.

May be help (^^)